# Province data not getting submitted on click

Tags: html, forms

I'm creating a sign up form as part of my assignment. The form data is getting submitted except for the province data. The provinces are in a dropdown list. I initially only had the value and thought that was the issue so I added the name and id but I'm still experiencing the same issue. What am I missing? I can't seem to figure it out. Below is my html code for the dropdown, checkboxes and radio button. I'm only using html.

```
            <h3>Which province are you from?</h3>
            <select>
                <option value="easternCape" name="province" id="=ec">Eastern Cape</option>
                <option value="freeState" name="province" id="fs">Free State</option>
                <option value="gauteng" name="province" id="gp">Gauteng</option>
                <option value="kwaZulu-Natal" name="province" id="kzn">KwaZulu-Natal</option>
                <option value="limpopo" name="province" id="lim">Limpopo</option>
                <option value="mpumalanga" name="province" id="mp">Mpumalanga</option>
                <option value="northWest" name="province" id="nw">North West</option>
                <option value="northernCape" name="province" id="nc">Northern Cape</option>
                <option value="westernCape" name="province" id="wc">Western Cape</option>
            </select><br>

            <h3>Preferred payment method</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pmtMthd" value="eft">EFT<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pmtMthd" value="cc">Credit Card<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="pmtMthd" value="ppal">Paypal<br>

            <h3>Preferred delivery method</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="method" value="courier">Courier<br>
            <input type="radio" name="method" value="post">Post<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are adding the ID and name to the options instead of the select tag itself.

```
<select name="province" id="province">
    <option value="easternCape">Eastern Cape</option>
    <option value="freeState">Free State</option>
    <option value="gauteng">Gauteng</option>
    <option value="kwaZulu-Natal">KwaZulu-Natal</option>
    <option value="limpopo">Limpopo</option>
    <option value="mpumalanga">Mpumalanga</option>
    <option value="northWest">North West</option>
    <option value="northernCape">Northern Cape</option>
    <option value="westernCape">Western Cape</option>
</select>
```

When getting the form result, pull the value from the name and ID "province" and you should get the selected value. *The select tag is a special "input" tag for a form, so you get the value from it instead of its options*

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you very much. This has solved my problem.